# how to resolve properties using regex

Tags: java, regex, properties-file

I have a Properties file (myfile.prop) with properties like:

```
name=sara
address=${this.address}
this.address=Bangalore
url=${abc}/${cde}
abc=lolkata
cde=florida
nested=${${this.work}.file}
this.work=engg
engg.file=mywork
```

I need to resolve these properties so that every time i get the resolved value.

Code for it is:

```
static String resolve(String str, Properties props, boolean isResolved)
   {
      if (props == null || str == null)
      {
         return str;
      }

      String expandedString = str;
      String macroPattern   = "(\\$\\{)([a-z.\\-A-Z0-9_]*)(\\})";   
      Pattern pattern       = Pattern.compile(macroPattern);
      Matcher m             = null;
      boolean pendingItems  = true;

      do
      {
         m = pattern.matcher(expandedString);
         pendingItems = false;
         String formerStr = expandedString;

         while (m.find())
         {
            pendingItems   = true;
            String propVal = (String)props.get(m.group(2));
            if (propVal == null)
            {
               propVal = m.group(0);
            }
            expandedString = expandedString.replace(m.group(0), propVal);

            if (!fullyResolve)
            {
               return expandedString;
            }
         }
         m.reset();

         /* if the string did not change at all, it is a sign that this
          * string cannot be resolved, just return */
         if (expandedString.equals(formerStr))
         {
            return expandedString;
         }
      }
      while (pendingItems);

      return expandedString.trim();
   }
```

but all it is doing is returning the value.... can some one tell me whats wrong with it?

Comment: By *"resolve properties **using** regex"* DYM *"resolve property values **as** regex"*?

Comment: Better on http://codereview.stackexchange.com I think.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [StrSubstitutor](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/text/StrSubstitutor.html) from Apache Commons Lang.

BTW, using regexps is not the most efficient for this purpose, I guess.